# Boyd & Vandenberghe's pointwise supremum notation

Tags: optimization, notation, convex-optimization, supremum-and-infimum

I am trying to understand the pointwise supremum from Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook).

> [image]

---

Let me try to share my understanding, please validate it. Let's try to visualise $g(x)$. $f(x,y)$ is a two variable function. for any particular x value say X and all y values we select maximum of $f(X,y)$ which is the slice of the surface $f(x,y)$  where y is varying over the entire y axis for a particular X?

What does the following mean?

$ y \in \mathcal A $

What is the set $ \mathcal A $? is it the set of y defined for function $f(x,y)$ and not the entire y axis?

the resulting g(x) may not be continuous right? but it maybe be convex?

Are $f(X,y)$ slices the infinite set of convex functions? Is it because $x$ and $y$ are on the reals?

Comment: What is the notation $\sup_{y\in\mathcal A\vert}$? Specifically the $\vert$. Normally this denotes the restriction to a subset but none is given.

Comment: @Math1000 Thanks for you answer. There is a small mistake in my screen grab. There is no $\vert $ sign after $\mathcal A$. Sorry, it was my cursor. Is $\mathcal A$ the set of y values in the domain of $f(x,y)$?